# PHP PDO mysql how to check if stored procedure is created

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Here I have a deliberate wrong SQL sintax

```
$conn = new PDO($host.$bd,$user,$pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = '
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mySP`;
    CREATE PROCEDURE `mySP`()
    BEGIN   
        IF (CALL whatewer()) THEN
            /*some*/
        ELSE
            /*go stuf*/
        END IF;
    END;
';  

$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute();

if(!$result){
    echo "BAD";
}else{
    echo "GOOD";
}
```

The problem:

- My if condition switch to else -> "GOOD"
- PDO not show any error
- The stored procedure is not created

If I remove the the first line **DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mySP`;** then PDO show the errors

The question:

How to check if one stored procedure is really created but using Drop procedure if exist also?

Comment: `prepare()/execute()` are intended for single parameterized statements. You are executing two DDL statements, and for that purpose you should be using `PDO::exec()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: Try out what you have by wrapping it all as `$conn->exec('all your SQL')` assuming the real SQL does not accept user input parameters. It may work immediately.

Comment: I have tried now $result = $conn->exec($sql); But still with the same problem.

Comment: For now to survive I use this: $result = $conn->exec($sql); $result = $conn->exec("CALL mySP();");